# SQL Server count with distinct with table alias

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I would like use `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` and with alias of table.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count 
FROM auth_users
```

This works, but I must use alias of table, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User.id) AS count 
FROM auth_users AS User
```

...and this returns an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

How to rebuild to work with the simplest way?

In MySQL both ways work fine :)

Comment: All 3 work fine for me in SQL Server. What is the issue.

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Sno) AS Count FROM  FileDetails
    
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FileDetails.Sno) AS count FROM FileDetails
    
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Alias.Sno) AS count FROM FileDetails AS Alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"User" is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql), so, if you want to use it as table alias you have to wrap it with square brackets, see examples below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [User].id) AS count FROM auth_users AS [User]
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS count FROM auth_users AS u
```